# I ran this code 'assoc.exe=xyz' from command prompt

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have problem. I ran this code `assoc.exe=xyz` from command prompt by purpose of disabling extensions from chrome web browser. But now all of my software programs were disabled including command prompt. please what should I do???

Comment: This works for me. See [TrishTech:How to Restore EXE File Association in Windows](http://www.trishtech.com/2011/05/restore-exe-file-association-in-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Power off the OSE (best if not using ATX, aka by wire or by hypervisor's power off command), then boot normally. Should make OSE reread main registry file and not logs, thus effectively roll back your change.

Comment: OSE is software to install or it is tool inside computer??

Comment: @ZanaQ.Mahmood OSE is short for "operating system environment". If you did that in a virtual machine, that VM is an OSE, if you have Windows 10 installed on your PC and no virtualization, the PC is OSE.

Comment: I use windows 10 but what is steps to do this procedure?

Comment: Perform a hard shutdown of your PC by holding power button for 4 seconds, this will make it power off. Then power it on and check if it works (it should).

Comment: Vasper, i did it does not work

Comment: Then boot from Windows 10 recovery DVD (or any other tool that's capable of reaching the affected system's registry), run there `regedit.exe`, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\exefile\shell\open\command` and change both values to `"%1" %*` (or one, if there's only the default value present), save and reboot.